# how to write the xpath (output) into a json file

Tags: javascript, testing, protractor

I have xpath example :element(by.xpath("xxx")) which will get me an output   that needs to write into json file ,can someone help  me on how to proceed in protractor.

Comment: Tried something like this never worked

var  fs = require('fs');
                           var track_num =element(by.xpath("xxxx"));

      
            var obj_parse = JSON.parse (track_num);



fs.writefile("../spec/object.json",JSON.stringify(track_num,null,4)).then(function(err)
 {
  if (err)
        {
          console.error(err);
          return;

        };

        console.log("file has been created")

});

Comment: You don't want to print out the protractor element as an object. Do you want the text of the element?

Comment: Thanks martin i figure it out to get the text and put it in the json file ,the only issue i am having is how to write in each line ,would appreciate if you can help me out

Answer (score 0):

```
var fs = require('fs'); // node.js file system
var filename = 'object.json';

element(by.xpath('xxx')).getText().then(function(text) {
    if (text) {
        var textAsJSON = JSON.parse(text);
        return fs.writeFileSync(fileName, textAsJSON);
        // or return fs.appendFileSync(filename, text);
    }
});
```